# Was there ever a Kryptonian Green Lantern?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, krypton

The Green Lantern Corps has members from species on planets throughout the universe.

At any point was someone from Krypton part of their number?

Comment: Do we count Daxamites? https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Sodam_Yat

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Last_Son_of_Earth - This one is quite interesting. It's an Elseworlds where a (human)  Clark is sent from Earth to Krypton, then becomes a Green Lantern.

Comment: Kal-El was also a Yellow Lantern; https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-2f48a8a534299fed9a86b40f52c785f2-lq

Comment: Superman was a Black Lantern; https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-0091962905e852f84ff2536f082d0a75-lq

Comment: Superman was a White Lantern; https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-4b1f9fbcaa41f5c88a1bb784a9111d69-lq

Comment: Minor nit: People are spelling the Green Lantern Corps as both “Corp.” and “Crops.” I guess autocomplete doesn’t suggest it?

Comment: I have a vague memory of a backup story somewhere which revealed that had Krypton not exploded, then Kal-El would have become its Green Lantern when he grew up.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you mean in what laughingly counts as the 'canon' DC Universe, then yes, there have been a couple.

[**Jan-Al of Krypton**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Jan-Al_(Prime_Earth)) was the earliest Kryptonian Green Lantern (and indeed one of the earliest Lanterns, period).

[image]
<sub><sup>[Green Lanterns Vol 1, #28](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lanterns_Vol_1_28)</sup></sub>

And a depowered Superman is also (very temporarily) gifted a Lantern ring in [*Superman: Up, Up and Away #2* "*Mild Mannered Reporter*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Up,_Up_and_Away!), although it's not clear what authority Hal Jordan had to grant him this ring and he gives it back shortly afterwards anyway.

[image]
<sub><sup>[*Superman: Up, Up and Away #2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Up,_Up_and_Away!)</sup></sub>

---

If we start digging into Elseworlds and What If... style comics, then there's loads.

[Kal-El](https://dcuguide.com/w/Kal-El_(Green_Lantern_of_Krypton)), for example, was a Green Lantern as depicted in *[JLA #8](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/JLA_Vol_1_8) "Imaginary Stories*"

[image]
<sub><sup>[JLA #8](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/JLA_Vol_1_8)</sup></sub>

As was [Kal-El](http://dcuguide.com/w/Kal-El_(Green_Lantern_of_Oa)), as depicted in *[Superman Vol. 2 #147](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_2_147) "Secret Origins Part 1: The Knight"*

[image]
<sub><sup>[Superman Vol. 2 #147](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_2_147)</sup></sub>

Superman (and the rest of the JLA) become Green Lanterns in the one-shot [*Batman: In Darkest Knight*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_In_Darkest_Knight), albeit not technically part of the official GL Corps.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Batman: In Darkest Knight](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_In_Darkest_Knight)</sup></sub>

Clark also becomes a Green Lantern in *[Smallville: Lantern](https://smallville.fandom.com/wiki/Smallville:_Lantern_Issue_1)*

[image]
*<sub><sup>[Smallville: Lantern #1](https://smallville.fandom.com/wiki/Smallville:_Lantern_Issue_1)</sup></sub>*

Comment: The Superman seen in DC One Million has a ring, but he's not a member of the GL Corp (as far as we can tell); https://2.bp.blogspot.com/kl5FdLl0M3gUjobjX6Yievtn6txRH_PvT0xHVMNSDD-b-44I6u7ISjC9sPGmJ_wRgKqCFfYjyu9f=s1600

Answer (score 2):

In the *Armageddon 2001* crossover (1991) Supes stole Guy Gardner's ring, and was offered membership of the GL Corps, but turned it down.

That was in a *possible* future, though, not part of regular continuity.
[image]

[image]

Comment: A good find. Have a +1 from me

Comment: Do all the strips in this answer correspond to a single story? If so, some context (if available) would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, they are from a single story. I  thought I had described the context.